# Form in Flask not working

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am trying to create a web page that takes user input and uses that input as a parameter in a separate .py file (so the .py file takes a string as a parameter)

The .py file works as it's supposed to be. But my form in html seems to be incorrect. I have something similar but haven't found quite what I am looking for.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/" method="get">
  <center>
    <div>
      Keyword: <input type="text" name="search" style="display:inline; width:482px;margin-top:50px" title="Enter a keyword">
      <input type="submit" value="Analyze" title="Click to search">
    </div>
     </center>
</form>
```

It is ok to use GET in this instance.

Here's my app.py

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import request 
from flask import render_template
from project import my_func
import json, urllib 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("index.html") #Set render template

@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        search= request.args.get('search')
        my_func(search) #passes the user input into the my_func as a parameter
        return  render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True #Uncomment to enable debugging
    app.run() #Run the Server
```

I believe that the error is in the GET form, I just if it's ok to do it this way.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: The 'vote down' should really come with an explanation attached. This would help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the action of the form is sending you back to the `my_form` function.

`<form action="/" method="get">` calls `@app.route('/')` and not `@app.route('/results')`.

Try change the form action to `/results`.

Comment: it did not change my results. Is it ok to call my_func() inside the app.py?

Comment: @ana it depends on where the project.py file is. Can you provide the project tree?

Comment: this is where the file is : C:/ --> myproject -->env --> project.py

Comment: Assuming app.py is at the same level that env you probably must call `from env.project import myfunc`. But if the project is an external package placed in a virtualenv (called env) and you are working with this virtualenv activated, then is ok to call it like you do in the provided example.

Comment: it is not on a virtualenv. app.py is inside the env folder and at the same level as project.py. So the idea is that if app.py and project.py are the same level, then it is ok to call as is, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can call it as `from .project import myfunc` rather. If this is a Python Package. Have you tried? Can you specify the error message?

Comment: It is not a package. Also, there is no error message. The code runs when I hit the submit button. I tried some debugging and the form works now, the issue is that it is not calling passing the input to my_func()correctly. The result is just 'none'

Comment: So the problem now is `my_func` and not the form anymore. Maybe you'll have to open another question and specify the content in `my_func`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to direct your form to page/function with the logic. Change your form's `action="/"` to `action="/results"`.

```
<form action="/results" method="get">
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).